# Why are Document Size and Window Size the Same On Load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am storing the offset of a div as a percentage of document size ({position_x: 0.50, position_y: 0.50} for example). That number is then multiplied by document width/height to get a pixel value I use to set the div's offset. The problem is that when first loading the document, document size and window size are being calculated as the same thing, so {position_x: 0.50, position_y: 0.50} is 50% of the window's 500px width/height and not the document's 1200px width/height. How can I get document size to render completely before setting the offset?

```js
$(function() {
var offset= {
  position_x: 0.5,
  position_y: 0.5
};

var offsetLeft = $(document).width() * offset.position_x;
var offsetTop = $(document).height() * offset.position_y;

$(".square").css({top: offsetTop, left: offsetLeft});
});
```

```css
.square
{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Document Size Test</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='square'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally document means the entire HTML document. Since you try to retrieve the height of document, as only the html window is visible, it gives the size of browser screen. But, in case of window, it targets the browser window. Eventually, both things are same at the initials.

Comment: What should I do in my case? set a timeout function to allow the document to fully render?